# Is ARCore compatible with Nexus 6P

Tags: android, arcore

Will ARCore run on my Nexus 6P?

The Google doc indicates it'll run on Android N phones but then states the SDK preview is more limited:

> ARCore is designed to work on a wide variety of qualified Android
>   phones running N and later. During the SDK preview, ARCore supports
>   the following devices:
>
> - Google Pixel and Pixel XL
> - Samsung Galaxy S8 (SM-G950U, SM-G950N, SM-G950FD, SM-G950FD, SM-G950W, SM-G950U1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Now Nexus 6P also supported. 
Please refer the links for supported device list https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

<strike>No, it won't be running on Nexus 6P. As they stated SDK preview will be limited to devices given in the docs. Let's hope they will add more supporting devices in coming days.</strike>

Comment: Follow the repo at https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk. Should receive updates when new stuff/phones are added

Comment: Isn't this an answer to the question "is it officially supported" vs "is it compatible/will it run?"  Given GoKo's response it seems like it _does_ run on a Nexus 6P if the device check is skipped, albeit not problem free.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Nexus 6P is currently supported

Comment: @JoaquinIurchuk thanks for the info I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is an modified arcore client library on github:

[Google ARCore for "unsupported" Android devices](https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all)

Replace the original arcore client library with the modified one in your project and it should work on your Nexus 6P or any other phone.
Tried it by myself on my Nexus 6P, but there's some lag and other problems.

Comment: Thanks! This is a real workaround in current situation

Comment: is this supported for all android devices ?

Answer (score 1):

ARCore doesn't work with Nexus 6P. If you want to get AR on 6P and older devices, there are kits like [8th wall XR](https://github.com/8thwall/xr-unity) or you can try [Vuforia](https://www.vuforia.com/).

Comment: 8th wall XR or Vuforia are not ARCore alternatives so far. 8th is unable to track position in ARCore or Tango unsupported devices.

Comment: Neither does ARCore on those devices. If you have a device without ARCore or ARKit support, 8th Wall XR (as of Oct 2017) only give you 3DoF which is better than nothing.

Comment: @wilk3ns - 8th Wall XR added support for position tracking (full 6-DoF) in December. See https://www.8thwall.com/8th-wall-xr-release-4-now-available/

Answer (score 1):

Current version of ARCore is compatible and available on Nexus 6p. 
I have installed it on my Nexus 6p from Play Store and it's working well.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices